# Comparing Multiple Lists of Data in Excel to Find Correlating Data

Tags: excel, compare

I thought I knew where to start with this but sadly I it's been long enough to where I need some assistance. First of all what I am working with is four lists of product data that I need to compare against my own product data.

So for example each of the product lists contain the following data:

```
Product Category
Product Name
Inventory
Product Price
```

Each of the lists have at least a thousand records.

What I need is a fifth list that tells me which of the competitors products I don't have on my list.

Last but not least and where this gets trickier is that the inventory contains duplicate records.

Its hard for me even to construct this question as I spend time with it.

What I want though is a list of products that are shared by all of the competitors that I do NOT have on my product list.

Comment: What column(s) serve as a key? In other words, are there specific values on each row of the various lists that you want to compare to your product list?

Comment: if you find a key (e.g. Product Names are exactly the same on different lists), you can add a formula on each competitor's list like `=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(B2;my_sheet!$B:$B;0));"ok";"not on my list")` and use an autofilter... + i suggest comparing the unmatched items manually, if not all the names are exact match (excel won't do the data cleaning for you, that is what interns are for)

Comment: Yes, the products column serves as the key.

Comment: Using match or vlookup could bring you the data, provide that there is a perfect match between the key values of your lists. If you require a more fuzzy match, which I expect when you are comparing competitors, you might want to try the fuzzy lookup add-in from Microsoft (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15011)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are familiar with PivotTables perhaps the multiple-consolidation ranges option could be used to suit your needs...

1. Select the multiple-consolidation ranges option by accessing the PivotTable wizard dialog (Shortcut: Alt+D+P) then enter settings in the dialog similar to below. The data is shown on the same sheet but could equally be stored in different sheets or even closed workbooks.
2. Rearrange columns and group product names into "Matched" and "Unmatched" as shown. There are several methods to automate the grouping, the simplest is probably to add a count column beside the pivottable and filter on rows where there are 4 items, then you can select visible items in the row field by pressing Alt+; and choose the group option. Rename this group "Matched", then filter for less than 4 items in the count column and rename the group "Unmatched"
3. Now you can compare all matched product names with your own list using a simple vlookup or otherwise.

[image]

[image]

Comment: + 1 Good one lori and yes...Nicely explained :)