# Counting Multiple Items in Excel Based on Specific Criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif, vba

I looked through other questions and couldn't find what I needed.

Best if I explain as followed:

I have a spreadsheet that has three columns in it:

Product Name
Vendor

Some vendors have the same product.

I need to count how many Product Names are identical by vendor.

All help is most appreciated.

Thank you,

user1114330

[image: Example Data]

Comment: I saw in one of your previous questions, http://stackoverflow.com/q/10610354/293078, you got a suggestions to use pivot tables.  For this question, which seems to be the same, or similar, project, pivot tables would also be the way to go.

Comment: Yeah this one is different than that last post.  A pivot table worked but for this one it will not.  The users will be using Google Docs and pivot tables are close to worthless in Gdocs.  I am using excel to prepare the reports and will import to gdocs when I am complete to share.

Comment: Maybe what I should do is take the unique product records, delete duplicates and then use some sort of vlookup with a countif?

Comment: To get a good answer you need to lay out the situation more.  Give an example of your data and the results you expect.

Comment: @DougGlancy - Examples above.

Comment: Do you need VBA for this? This can be solved using a simple excel formula...

Comment: @SiddharthRout - Would love to know that simple formula, Sir. I believe you are right but I am lost...haven't spent much time in excel lately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paste this formula in Cell C1

```
 =SUMPRODUCT(($A$1:$A$10=A1)*($B$1:$B$10=B1))
```

**SNAPSHOT**

[image]

However if you still want VBA, see this

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lrow As Long

    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        lrow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("C1:C" & lrow).Formula = "=SUMPRODUCT(($A$1:$A$" & lrow & _
                                        "=A1)*($B$1:$B$" & lrow & "=B1))"
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you...do you have any suggestions on how to use the first non-vba script against 102k rows?

Comment: Yup. Change the $10 in the above formula to the last row number and then put the formula in Cell C1. After that simply double click on the autofill so that the formulas copy down till the last cell.

Comment: =SUMPRODUCT(($G$2:$G$102667=G2)*($H$2:$H$102667=H2))  Isn't working..shows #VALUE! ..thoughts?

Comment: Where have you put this formula? I2? Also can you upload a snapshot of your data?

Comment: Its in K2..no sorry no snapshot upload available, I only have 9 rep points, need 10.

Comment: Ok I just upped your post. Try it now :-)

Comment: Hope I caught you..take a look at the example.  Your formula works only until I use the amount of rows mentioned above (~102k).

Comment: BTW - Thanks for voting my question up.

Comment: That's strange, it works perfectly on my end. If you want, can you upload your file in www.wikisend.com and share the link here?

Comment: got it working!  There was a #VALUE! that prevented any numbers from being reported.  Thank you!!

Comment: This does work although not very fast.  Do you have any suggestions on the way to process something like this the fastest?  Going very very slow...

Comment: A pivot table as suggested by Doug will be very fast.

Comment: If you have Excel 2007 or later you can use COUNTIFS which is much quicker in Excel, i.e.=COUNTIFS(G:G,G2,H:H,H2)

Comment: that's a lot of formulas...I still find excel very slow when sheets have 100k of formulas in them. Generally means that somebody needs to use SQL better before the data even gets to Excel.

Comment: Why wouldn't you use a Pivot?

Comment: I must be missing something obvious. I looked at the OP's sumproduct formula and yours, they look identical. So why does yours work and his doesn't?