# Converting Excel Forumla to MySQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql, excel, excel-formula

I had an answer to question [**here:**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11066870/counting-multiple-items-in-excel-based-on-specific-criteria)

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$1:$A$10=A1)*($B$1:$B$10=B1))
```

and

```
=COUNTIFS(G:G,G2,H:H,H2)
```

Both get the job done however are extremely slow. I believe I need to do this with SQL instead with hundred thousand plus rows.

What I would like to know is how would I accomplish the same number in SQL?

I imagine I could put my unique vendors in a table and then insert my products into a table while pulling my `vendorsID` from the `vendors` table.

At this point I would have two tables...in the `vendors` table I could add another column for the # of products per vendor (like explained in the above link) and a products table that has the product name and the vendorID.

Question is how would this query look? Query one table to populate the other table with the product and vendor ID *think* I understand however actually making the calculation I need (amount of matching products per vendor) I am completely lost.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have populated the two tables:

**Vendors:**

- `Id`, `Name`.

**Products:**

- `Id`, `VendorId`, `Name`...

Then, In order to:

> count how many Product Names are identical by vendor.

You should do something like:

```
SELECT v.Id, v.Name, COUNT(p.Id) AS 'Total Products'
FROM Vendors v INNER JOIN Products p ON v.Id = p.VendorId
GROUP BY v.Id, v.Name
```

**Edit:** If you want to insert this result set that you got from this query into another table you should use [`INSERT ... SELECT` Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html), something like:

```
INSERT INTO NewTable(VendorId, VendorName, ProductsCount)
SELECT v.Id, v.Name, COUNT(p.Id) AS 'Total Products'
FROM Vendors v INNER JOIN Products p ON v.Id = p.VendorId
GROUP BY v.Id, v.Name
```

**Edit2:** To update an existing table that already has vendors list, you should update the table by joining it with the result set

```
UPDATE ExistingTable t
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT v.Id, v.Name, COUNT(p.Id) AS 'TotalProducts'
    FROM Vendors v INNER JOIN Products p ON v.Id = p.VendorId
    GROUP BY v.Id, v.Name
) v ON t.VendorId = v.Id
SET t.VendorId = v.Id, t.VendorName = v.Name, t.ProductsCount = v.TotalProducts
```

Comment: and to insert it into another table? Thank you!!

Comment: I want to perform the count similar to your example and insert the result of the query into another table. Make sense?

Comment: would be really nice to know how to make a script that perform this query when I upload data to a specific table but I suppose thats another question...

Comment: @user1114330, What do you mean by updating an existing table, Do you mean update all the existing vendors id's with the count values from the result set? or updating the table by inserting these new values??

Comment: yes updating existing vendor IDs with the count values. Not sure the difference in your last question though?

Comment: @user1114330, See my edit it should work for you but I am not sure about updating the `VendorId`, but this is the right syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the table structure as in excel ie one table: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fb9f3/1

The SQL would be as below:

```
SELECT vendor, product, SUM(qty) from tblOrder 
GROUP BY vendor, product
```